# Can a Trie be implemented externally?

Tags: data-structures, information-retrieval, trie

Can we process a large number of unique words (~1 GB data) and make a trie of them to answer simple queries like:

- How many words share a prefix `xyz`?
- Given a prefix `abc`, what is the most frequent next letter? (from `abca`, `abcb`, ..., `abcz`)

The only issue is that the size of the file is not allowing me to store the trie in-memory.

Can a trie be implemented externally? Is there any other way to answer these queries on large datasets?

P.S. The other way I was approaching the problem was to [externally sort the words](https://github.com/lemire/externalsortinginjava) and implement binary search to find the first and last occurrence of the prefix. Then subtracting the positions to find the count.

Comment: 1 GB of data isn't actually a lot, given that most modern machines have oodles of those. There are more and less efficient ways to implement tries -- naive approaches that dynamically allocate arrays for every level consume much more than approaches that use linked lists, radix trees or Patricia trees. Certainly any data that's stored in-memory can also be stored on disk instead, it just complicates the implementation.

Comment: I think you actually want a FST structure like lucene uses, like this blog post (requires sorting to build) https://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/